# How to get a bootstrap select to fill the whole column width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the airport selector on the page www.parking-discounts.com/quote to cover the whole of the column width that I have given it, I think there is a class that does that but I am just not sure what it is...

```
<form id="parking-discounts-quote-form" class="form-inline radius" action="https://www.purplebusinessparking.com/cool-ice/default.asp" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" value="new_purple" name="Category">
                <input type="hidden" value="AirportsPriceQuote" name="Service">
                <input type="hidden" value="WDAD" name="sourceI">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label>Airport?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9"><select type="select" name="ap" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="ALL">Please Select:</option><option value="ABZ">Aberdeen</option><option value="BFS">Belfast Intl</option><option value="BHX">Birmingham</option><option value="BOH">Bournemouth</option><option value="BRS">Bristol</option><option value="CWL">Cardiff</option><option value="DSA">Doncaster</option><option value="DOV">Dover</option><option value="MME">Durham Tees Valley</option><option value="EMA">East-Midlands</option><option value="EDI">Edinburgh</option><option value="EXT">Exeter</option><option value="LGW">Gatwick</option><option value="GLA">Glasgow</option><option value="LHR">Heathrow</option><option value="LBA">Leeds-Bradford</option><option value="LPL">Liverpool</option><option value="LCY">London City</option><option value="SEN">London Southend</option><option value="LTN">Luton</option><option value="MAN">Manchester</option><option value="NCL">Newcastle</option><option value="PIK">Prestwick</option><option value="SOU">Southampton</option><option value="SOP">Southampton Port</option><option value="STN">Stansted</option>
                                  </select></div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>Departure Date:</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select type="select" name="stdate" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                    <option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option><option value="04">04</option><option value="05">05</option><option value="06">06</option><option value="07">07</option><option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
                                                                  </select> <strong>/</strong>
                                            <select type="select" name="stmonth" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                    <option value="January">January</option><option value="February">February</option><option value="March">March</option><option value="April">April</option><option value="May">May</option><option value="June">June</option><option value="July">July</option><option value="August">August</option><option value="September">September</option><option value="October">October</option><option value="November">November</option><option value="December">December</option>
                                                                  </select></select> <strong>/</strong>
                                            <select type="select" name="styear" class="form-control">
                                                                    <option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                                  </select> <strong>at</strong> 

                                            <select type="select" name="arrivhour" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                        <option value="00">00</option><option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option><option value="04">04</option><option value="05">05</option><option value="06">06</option><option value="07">07</option><option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option>
                                                                      </select></select> <strong>:</strong>
                                            <select type="select" name="arrivmin" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                        <option value="00">00</option></option><option value="05">05</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option>
                                                                      </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>Return Date:</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <select type="select" name="rtrndate" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                    <option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option><option value="04">04</option><option value="05">05</option><option value="06">06</option><option value="07">07</option><option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
                                                                  </select> <strong>/</strong>
                                            <select type="select" name="rtrnmonth" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                    <option value="January">January</option><option value="February">February</option><option value="March">March</option><option value="April">April</option><option value="May">May</option><option value="June">June</option><option value="July">July</option><option value="August">August</option><option value="September">September</option><option value="October">October</option><option value="November">November</option><option value="December">December</option>
                                                                  </select> <strong>/</strong>
                                            <select type="select" name="rtrnyear" class="form-control">
                                                                    <option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                                  </select> <strong>at</strong> 
                                            <div class="clearfix visible-xs" style="padding-top:5px"></div>
                                            <select type="select" name="rtrnhour" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                    <option value="00">00</option><option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option><option value="04">04</option><option value="05">05</option><option value="06">06</option><option value="07">07</option><option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option>
                                                                  </select> <strong>:</strong>
                                            <select type="select" name="rtrnmin" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">
                                                                    <option value="00">00</option></option><option value="05">05</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option>
                                                                  </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>Passengers?</label>
                            <select type="select" name="passengers" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="001">1</option><option value="002">2</option><option value="003">3</option><option value="004">4</option><option value="005">5</option><option value="006">6</option><option value="007">7</option><option value="008">8</option><option value="009">9</option><option value="010">10</option><option value="011">11</option><option value="012">12</option><option value="013">13</option><option value="014">14</option><option value="015">15</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:0 0 10px;">GET A QUOTE</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: The class is there `form-control`, so the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: But why is it not spanning correctly, as there are other elements below but nothing that should affect this

Comment: Please show the whole form.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer below

Comment: This works in isolation. http://jsfiddle.net/stabw0h2/ It's something elsewhere.

Comment: That is the whole for, I have checked using inspect element that nothing else is affecting this but I cannot see it

Comment: Adding the included CSS files from your site to the jsfiddle may help.

Comment: The solution may be as easy as removing the inline style attribute you have set on the element `<select type="select" name="stdate" class="form-control" style="width: 75px">`. (i.e., `style="width: 75px"`).

Comment: Nevermind, wrong element.